# Date values from SQL cannot be filtered in EXCEL

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, sql

I created a VIEW in SQL which contains a date column. 
The date column is defined as datetime ,I had to use CONVERT (nvarchar.mydate,103) so I can get the following format : dd/mm/yyyy.

Now when I connect from EXCEL to get this data view,I am getting the date as follow :

[image]

I want them to be displayed as years so I have to use the **Text to columns** option and convert them.

[image]

The problem that I need to do this every time after I refresh the sheet. Is there a way that I can get the date automatically to be filtered by years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the date from SQL without converting it and apply the proper format in Excel.
Otherwise you will have to convert it back from text to number in Excel.